# Table View updates faster when scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view in my view controller, and when I hit a button, it should search for data online and fill in the table view cells. For some reason when I run the following code, it takes ~10 seconds to load the table view. But, if I hit search then slide the table view 1 second after, it loads instantly. Is there any way I can make it load instantly without having to scroll down it?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.songField) {
        [self.songField resignFirstResponder];

        NSString *searchString = self.songField.text;
        NSString *encodedSearchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *finalSearchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=%@&entity=song&limit=10",encodedSearchString];
        NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:finalSearchString];
        dispatch_queue_t iTunesQueryQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        dispatch_async(iTunesQueryQueue, ^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:searchURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

            if (data && !error) {
                NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                trackName = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackName"] mutableCopy];
                artistName = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.artistName"] mutableCopy];
                artwork = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.artworkUrl100"] mutableCopy];
                preview = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.previewUrl"] mutableCopy];
                linkData = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackViewUrl"] mutableCopy];
                if ([trackName count] == 0) {
                    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
                    [self.noResultsLabel setHidden:NO];
                }
                else {
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                    [self.cancelButton setHidden:YES];
                }
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reloading the tableView in background thread.
Reload the tableView, as well as perform all UI related tasks on main thread:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.songField) {
        [self.songField resignFirstResponder];

        NSString *searchString = self.songField.text;
        NSString *encodedSearchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *finalSearchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=%@&entity=song&limit=10",encodedSearchString];
        NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:finalSearchString];
        dispatch_queue_t iTunesQueryQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        dispatch_async(iTunesQueryQueue, ^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:searchURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

            if (data && !error) {
                NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                trackName = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackName"] mutableCopy];
                artistName = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.artistName"] mutableCopy];
                artwork = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.artworkUrl100"] mutableCopy];
                preview = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.previewUrl"] mutableCopy];
                linkData = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackViewUrl"] mutableCopy];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {
                if ([trackName count] == 0) {
                        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                        [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
                        [self.noResultsLabel setHidden:NO];
                    }
                    else {
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                        [self.cancelButton setHidden:YES];
                    }
            }
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: That works. One problem though. I hit the search button and it says there are no results. Then I hit it again and it loads correctly. I placed that code right after the `});` in my code above by the way.

Comment: I put the code before the `});` and it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the UI related work on main thread will help you achieve what you are trying to do
// once you get a callback from server and you are done parsing the data, call following inside your outer dispatch block

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_mainQueue(), ^{
// do your UI work here eq reloading tabelView
      [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```